# Key Chain three set of public/private keys

Tags: keychain

In Key Chain Access, I can see I have 3 sets of private/public keys, I suspect they are actually the same one set.
Can I find out somehow? Is it possible that Key Chain somehow got to store duplicates?

I know I have one key pair used for Github, that's it, no idea if the 2 remaining sets are identical or different and for what are they used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can find out by comparing the fingerprints of the keys.

In Keychain Access, click the ">" icon to the left of the key you want to examine to bring out the certificate. Double-click the certificate to open up the detailed information. Scroll to the very bottom and you'll find the fingerprint of the key.

Compare the fingerprint of the three keys - if they have different fingerprints, they're not duplicates.